# Did Jagdgeschwader 7 operate any Bf-109s?

Tags: world-war-two

I know the photo of "white 44" is JG 301, and that the photo of "yellow 20" is a training squadron. However, Revell of Germany came out with a kit that had II/JG 7 Bf-109G-10 "white 4" as an option. Is this historically accurate? Any information or help with would be appreciated, not just about this plane, but any JG 7 Bf-109s.
[image: Photo of a plane]

Comment: All answers are expected to show sources.   ("Please show sources") is like asking that water be wet.

Comment: As far as I know, they did not operate anything except Me-262, but Bf-109 G is sometimes listed as planned. It is possible that Bf-109s (alongside with newly trained pilots)  were diverted to other  Jagdgeschwader that had more experience with them  http://www.ww2.dk/air/jagd/jg7.htm

Comment: This question could be useful to you : https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/62776/during-the-wwii-did-the-german-luftwaffe-ever-have-mixed-units-of-bf-109s-and-m?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

According to this description of [German Aircraft of WWII](http://www.germanaircraftwwii.org/2015/04), [Bf-109's](http://www.germanaircraftwwii.org/2015/04/messerschmitt-bf-109-part-iii.html) [with the distinctive tail markings of JG 7](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zdj2a9MPb4U/VTTDf5fw-HI/AAAAAAAAwjY/xwGGJQvmfls/s1600/ydhjyjdh.jpg) were captured by the allies. According to [Wikipedia for Jagdgeschwader 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagdgeschwader_7) no surviving documentation exists on the role for such Bf-109s; but general belief  is that they flew *top cover* for the ME-262s.

[image]